# Getting Invalid parameter: Specified *** for the certificate associated with Proxy is incorrect. Azure Dev ops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management

I am getting 
**Invalid parameter: Specified *** for the certificate associated with Proxy is incorrect.** When I am running Import-AzureRmApiManagementHostnameCertificate on Azure Devops using Azure PowerShell Task

Same command works fine on locally.

Comment: Why does it say "Specified *"? Did you mean "Specified password"?

Comment: Did it work in powershell on your local machine?